# Converting UTF-8 characters to Microsoft Word (DOCX) with PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, ms-word, docx

We convert articles to Microsoft Word (DOCX) using PHP. The problem is that sometimes the articles contain special UTF-8 characters. I tried using htmlentities, but this doesn't solve the problem (it solved articles with "&" in them). Do you know what I should do in order to convert the UTF-8 characters to DOCX?

Comment: What lib are you using to write the DOCX files?

Comment: If you're creating a real .docx file, then the xml content should all be UTF-8 anyway

Comment: what do you mean by 'special' utf8 characters? symbols or language-specific characters (like the german umlaut)? are you able to write only ascii?

Comment: @MarkBaker You are absolutely correct, but because of `I tried using htmlentities, but this doesn't solve the problem (it solved articles with "&" in them)` I suspect he is using some kind of HTML->docx converter that doesn't understand unicode.

Comment: DOCX is able to handle Unicode. Your conversion error must reside somewhere else…

Comment: @DaveRandom - my suspicion (sadly borne out all too aften) as that html markup is being saved as a file with a .docx extension

Comment: We are using ZipArchive() to save the file in zip format.

Comment: Is there a problem using htmlentities() before creating the file?

Comment: The special UTF-8 character in this case is "–" (a dash) - it looks as "â€“" in PhpMyAdmin (by the way how do I fix PhPMyAdmin to display the dash?). With the dash Microsoft Word can't open the DOCX file. If I replace all the dashes with "-" (minus), it works. But I want to keep the dash and convert it to DOCX.

Comment: I have also seen MSWord itself not display UTF-8 characters correctly because the FONT being used doesn't have the required character defined.  You might want to confirm that before tracing through code-paths to look for where UTF-8 is not being used.  I think Docmosis and JODReports can generate Doc/DocX with UTF-8 end-to-end if those systems help you (it would be cmd-line invoke I guess).

Answer (score 0):

OK, We found a solution. We started using [PHPDOCX](http://www.phpdocx.com) for creating the DOCX files, and now everything works fine.